# input field has php array but does not record first element

Tags: php, html

have simple input field in a form , where i collect answers to questions, so the name is an array; but when i post the form, what gets posted is wrong

```
<form name='getanswers' method = 'POST' action = 'DQSaveAnswers.php/'>
<? for($i=0; $i<3 ; $i++) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?echo $question[$i] ;?> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="myAnswer[]" class="myclass" id="myAnswer[]" 
> </td>
<td><?echo $qPoints[$i] ;?> </td>
<td> <input type="hidden" name ="qId[]" value="<?echo $qId[$i];?>" > 
</td>
<td> <input type="hidden" name ="question[]" value="<?echo 
$question[$i];?>"></td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
```

this is the simple code - where i print 3 questions (come from db); next to that input field to capture user answers etc.
when i print the "myAnswer[]" and "qId[]" in the DQsqveAnswers.php i get correct results for qId[] but dont get right results for myAnswer[].
this is what i have in DQSaveAnswers.php

```
$answers = array();
$qId = array();
$answers=$_POST['myAnswer'];
$question=$_POST['question'];
$qId=$_POST['qId'];

echo "id are ";
print_r($qId);
echo "answers are ";
print_r($answers);
echo " and questions are ".print_r($question);
```

As a user i enter values "RR" , "dc",1

and output i get printed is
id are

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

answers are

```
Array ( [0] => dc [1] => 1 )

Array ( [0] => who will win today(Match1) 
        [1] => who will be the man of the match(Match1- pl copy/paste from list below) 
        [2] => how many sixers will be hit(Match1) 
      )
```

check what comes after "answers are" ... only 2 values that too are incorrect the first value RR is missed ..
not sure whats going wrong , as the `$qId` gets printed correctly

Comment: did you check ALL is coming by POST? 
<? print_r ($_POST); ?>

Comment: Hey again. I run your code in my server, only adding a submit button and closing the form tag. And it sent all 3 results: Array
(
    [myAnswer] => Array
        (
            [0] => aa
            [1] => bb
            [2] => cc
        )

So, the problem it's not the in code you posted here. Try what I wrote before, printing the entire $_POST and tell us what happened.

Comment: thanks so much for the replies folks..  i tried priting Print_r($_POST)  here is what i get       Array ( [qId] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) [question] => Array ( [0] => who will win today(Match1) [1] => who will be the man of the match(Match1- pl copy/paste from list below) [2] => how many sixers will be hit(Match1) ) [myAnswer] => Array ( [0] => rahane [1] => 18 ) [B1] => Submit )      As you can see , the [myAnswer] array does not print 3 values (I had  entered 3)

Comment: also , i do have submit button on the form - just that i did not post it earlier        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2">

Comment: i think i got the problem .. my form and table elements were not properly aligned !! stupid of me to waste time.